# HTML page with inside JavaScript not opening in mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, mobile-safari, hammer.js

I have created one .html file, a full calendar and hammer.js.

It’s working on desktop and Android devices. I can see the full calendar and gesture of swipe left and swipe right. But it’s only not working on mobile Safari.

I have mailed the HTML file and am trying to open the fullCalendar.html page from my mail or from WhatsApp. But it shows a white screen only in [iPhone XS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone_XS) Max (Safari).

In mobile Safari the normal HTML file is working fine, but with JavaScript it’s not loading anything.

Head:

```js
! function(a) {
  function f(a, b) {
    if (!(a.originalEvent.touches.length > 1)) {
      a.preventDefault();
      var c = a.originalEvent.changedTouches[0],
        d = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
      d.initMouseEvent(b, !0, !0, window, 1, c.screenX, c.screenY, c.clientX, c.clientY, !1, !1, !1, !1, 0, null), a.target.dispatchEvent(d)
    }
  }
  if (a.support.touch = "ontouchend" in document, a.support.touch) {
    var e, b = a.ui.mouse.prototype,
      c = b._mouseInit,
      d = b._mouseDestroy;
    b._touchStart = function(a) {
      var b = this;
      !e && b._mouseCapture(a.originalEvent.changedTouches[0]) && (e = !0, b._touchMoved = !1, f(a, "mouseover"), f(a, "mousemove"), f(a, "mousedown"))
    }, b._touchMove = function(a) {
      e && (this._touchMoved = !0, f(a, "mousemove"))
    }, b._touchEnd = function(a) {
      e && (f(a, "mouseup"), f(a, "mouseout"), this._touchMoved || f(a, "click"), e = !1)
    }, b._mouseInit = function() {
      var b = this;
      b.element.bind({
        touchstart: a.proxy(b, "_touchStart"),
        touchmove: a.proxy(b, "_touchMove"),
        touchend: a.proxy(b, "_touchEnd")
      }), c.call(b)
    }, b._mouseDestroy = function() {
      var b = this;
      b.element.unbind({
        touchstart: a.proxy(b, "_touchStart"),
        touchmove: a.proxy(b, "_touchMove"),
        touchend: a.proxy(b, "_touchEnd")
      }), d.call(b)
    }
  }
}(jQuery);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Calendar</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.7.0/fullcalendar.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id='calendar'></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js?v=1.1"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.17/jquery-ui.min.js?v=1.1"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.3/moment.js?v=1.1"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.7.0/fullcalendar.js?v=1.1"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.8/hammer.min.js?v=1.1"></script>
  <script>
    $('#widget').draggable();
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {

      (function(factory) {
        if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
          define(['jquery', 'hammerjs'], factory);
        } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
          factory(require('jquery'), require('hammerjs'));
        } else {
          factory(jQuery, Hammer);
        }
      }(function($, Hammer) {
        function hammerify(el, options) {
          var $el = $(el);
          if (!$el.data("hammer")) {
            $el.data("hammer", new Hammer($el[0], options));
          }
        }
        $.fn.hammer = function(options) {
          return this.each(function() {
            hammerify(this, options);
          });
        };

        // extend the emit method to also trigger jQuery events
        Hammer.Manager.prototype.emit = (function(originalEmit) {
          return function(type, data) {
            originalEmit.call(this, type, data);
            $(this.element).trigger({
              type: type,
              gesture: data
            });
          };
        })(Hammer.Manager.prototype.emit);
      }));

      $(document).ready(function() {
        // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
        var calendar = $('#calendar');
        calendar.fullCalendar();

        //Hammer Js swipe
        calendar.hammer().on("swipeleft", function(event) {
          calendar.fullCalendar('next');
        });
        calendar.hammer().on("swiperight", function(event) {
          calendar.fullCalendar('prev');
        });
      });

    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Above is my code for the same. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You should turn on the iPhone Debug Console to find out what errors are happening. https://www.lifewire.com/activate-the-debug-console-in-safari-445798#:~:text=Here's%20how%3A,each%20display%20in%20the%20debugger.

Comment: @warnakey I tried this but it shows only html code. script that I code for full calendar is missing. all scripts that I added are not there.

Comment: What do you mean by *"inside JavaScript"*? *"lnlne JavaScript"*? Or something else?